# Achieving url redirection from a html to aspx page by querying the url parameters

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, redirect

This is going to be a long one.

I have a requirement where i have to use url redirection in my legacy web page (basically its a complete static html page).

The requirement for me is to redirect the user everytime, from the static html page to a .aspx page

i.e if my earlier page were found to be at

http://web.vatsag.com/app/en/downloadsite.htm

then i have to redirect to the following page (.aspx)

http://web.vatsag.com/app/newdownloadsite.aspx

At present i use the javascript in my html page,

i.e

```
window.location="http://web.vatsag.com/app/newdownloadsite.aspx"
```

script in the **head** section of my **downloadsite.htm** page

Now comes the question

How do i query multiple URL parameters ?

i.e. 
when the URL request is something like

```
http://web.vatsag.com/app/en/downloadsite.htm?lang=de&vers=1.10
```

I should be redirected to the aspx page with the same URL parameters.

```
http://web.vatsag.com/app/newdownloadsite.aspx?lang=de&vers=1.10
```

I have a javascript snippet which returns me the url parameters

```
function getQueryStringArray(){
    var assoc=[]; 
    var items = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&'); 
    for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) { 
       var a = items[j].split('='); assoc[a[0]] = a[1]; 
    }
    return assoc;
}
```

How do i use this snippet to get all the URL parameters to finally redirect to the ASPX web page?

Many thanks for the help

VATSAG

Comment: Have you thought about simply routing directly to the .aspx page instead of redirecting? Scott Guthrie has a blog post: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Comment: Using the server to do a url-rewrite suggested above is better imo. You don't have to put the javascript to all your legacy pages, nor does the client have to load the legacy pages first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code will get you the URL you are after

```
// Original URL
var url = window.location.href; 
var newUrl = "";

// Split the String to get the Query strings
var splitString = url.split('?');


if (splitString.length > 1)
{
   // New Url With Query strings
   newUrl = "http://web.vatsag.com/app/newdownloadsite.aspx" + "?" + splitString[1];
}
else
{
   // New Url With NO query string
   newUrl = "http://web.vatsag.com/app/newdownloadsite.aspx"
}
```

Comment: Thanks... that was real neat & simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Your task can easily be completed through the use of a simple meta tag on your old page which can redirect to your new page.

add the following line to the head section of your old static html page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=new_page_url" />
```

Comment: This will not serve the purpose, if he wants to query the URL parameters in querystring.

Answer (score 0):

window.location is not a string, it's a struct/class. It has its own member variables. When you assign `location="something"` you assign to the href member. You may check out its other members.

Also, on another note: Specifying entire address like `http://web.vatsag.com/app/newdownloadsite.aspx` is not recommended. Instead, use `../newdownloadsite.aspx`. This will help in case you relocate your site in future.

To answer your question, try:

```
  location=location.pathname.replace(/en\/downloadsite.htm$/,"newdownloadsite.aspx") + location.search + location.hash;
  //Host name, protocol, port number is taken from current one. (Making it more portable)
  //By using pathname.replace, you ensure that if the directory path depth of the original html page on server is changed, still it would be portable.
```

Btw, answer by MVCKarl - `.split("?")[1]` - should also work in place of `location.search + location.hash`.